# Computing a company's shareholders ownership percentage

Tags: java, matrix, graph, linear-algebra, graph-algorithm

I have a graph that contains two types of nodes: Companies and Persons.

A Company node has a list of edges that represent Shareholders. A Shareholder has a percentage of shares and is either a Company or a Person. A Person node is always a leaf.

Here's an example:

```
CompanyA has 50% of CompanyB's shares
UserA has 50% of CompanyA's shares
UserB has 50% of CompanyB's shares
CompanyB has 50% of CompanyA's shares
```

*The arrows could be reversed, depending on whether they represent shares or owners*

[image: Company shareholders]

Who in truth owns CompanyA and with what percentage. In this example, we should get that UserA owns 66.66% of CompanyA and UserB owns 33.33% of CompanyB.

This can be computed using a Transition Matrix and multiplying it by itself multiple times, [like this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0,.5,.5,0%7D,%7B.5,0,0,.5%7D,%7B0,0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,1%7D%7D%5E100).

Sadly, this is an estimate and requires quite a lot of iterations to get a very precise one. I suspect that there's a way to get a exact answer. I've looked at eigenvalues but I think my maths are failing me. In terms of matrices, I think I'm looking for the stable distribution of a transition matrix (or Markov Chain).

Perhaps I'm overcomplicating this? I feel like there should be a way to get this result without resolving to matrices and with a recursive algorithm. Especially considering that the graph contains a lot of leaves and that I am only interested in the shareholders of a single company (the "root" of the graph).

I will implement the final solution in Java. Third party libraries can be used.

Thanks!

Comment: Eigenvalues is indeed the way to go. They can be calculated very efficiently especially for sparse matrices.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem any idea why when I try to get the left eigenvalues for this example, I get two eigenvalues with value `1`? [I'm not sure how to interpret this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors(transpose%7B%7B0,.5,.5,0%7D,%7B.5,0,0,.5%7D,%7B0,0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,1%7D%7D))

Comment: @GuiSim have you tried asking this question on the [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)? They may get you further than we can.. Also... would love to know the answer if you found one

Comment: @zelusp In hindsight, I should have posted in the Math stack exchange! 

We decided to go with a different approach that didn't require as much maths. When we encounter a cycle, we backtrack to the root of the cycle, spreading the cycle's shares proportionally along the way.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the labeling of your matrix is more or less like so

```
   cA  cB  uA  uB
cA 0    0.5 0.5 0
cB 0.5  0   0   0.5
uA 0    0   1   0
uB 0    0   0   1
```

where cA/B denotes Company A/B while uA/B stands for User A/B.

Let's denote this matrix as `A`. Then the expression `(1, 0, 0, 0).A` gives us the immediate "distribution of resources" after "investing" 1 "unit" into Company A. In this case the result is indeed `(0, 0.5, 0.5, 0)`, i.e., Company B gets 50% and User A gets 50% as well. However, the resources attributed to Company B "propagate" further, so in order to find the "equilibrium" distribution, we need to calculate

```
(1, 0, 0, 0).A^n
```

in the limit of `n` going to infinity. In terms of the left eigenvectors, the original matrix `A` can be rewritten (assuming that it is diagonalizable) as `A=Inverse[P].w.P`, where `w` is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues. Then one has

```
A^n = (Inverse[P].w.P)^n = Inverse[P].w^n.P
```

In this particular case, the eigenvalues are `1, 1, 0.5, -0.5` so when `n` goes to infinity, only the eigenvalue `1` survive(s). Thus the limit of `w^n` is `DiagonalMatrix[{1,1,0,0}]`. The final result can be therefore written as

```
Inverse[P].DiagonalMatrix[{1,1,0,0}].P
```

which yields

```
0.  0.  0.666667    0.333333
0.  0.  0.333333    0.666667
0.  0.  1.  0.
0.  0.  0.  1.
```

Finally, the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue 1 are `(0, 0, 1, 0)` and `(0, 0, 0, 1)`. The meaning of this is that if one "invests" 1 unit of resources into User A/B, the corresponding user "keeps everything" and nothing propagates further, i.e., an equilibrium has been already reached. The eigenvalue is then doubly degenerate since there are two Users (leaves).